# Why the debate on where Shlishi is in parshat Terumah?

Tags: torah-reading, parashat-teruma

I use "Trope Trainer" for studying my weekly parsha reading. I like it b/c I can print the pages only for one parsha instead of shlepping the entire Tikun.

I noticed that for this week's parsha, Terumah, they have two options based on where Shlishi is.

1. Shlishi at Exodus 25:31
2. Shlishi at Exodus 26:1

From what I can tell, option 1 wants to keep reading about the menorah together with the description of the mishkan's poles, while option 2 keeps the menorah's description together with that of the shulchan (table).

Essentially, it seems that the debate is related somewhow to the reading about the menorah. But, I don't understand what the debate is or why it's there.

Comment: A possibly related insight is the placement of the oil making for the menorah in parshas Titzaveh, next to the bigdei kehuna, and not in Truma with the other items for the klei mishkan.

Comment: @user6591 - Can you expand on this insight? I'm not seeing the parallelism.

Comment: It seems to parallel what you listed as option one,(the more common minhag i think) where the menorah is separated from the other kli mishkan and placed with a seeming unrelated item. The oil which is used for the menorah seemingly ended up as well out of place.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/59414/759 I don't know that you need to read that much into this. There are lots of variants out there.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yup. I know about that article. As I haven't had a chance to read it, I can't honestly debate on your comment either way. There may still be some inherent reason for this. The beginning of Breishit is also known for different arrangements. Things such as this bother me, somewhat. I practice using an app which has it one way, but my shul, using the Hertz Chumash, has it a different way.

Comment: @DanF What is bugging you? there are dozens of traditions. just because you found one place where there's a differnece isn't significant at all.